# Docker ENTRYPOINT With a Piped Command

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a dockerfile that uses a combination of [rtlamr](https://github.com/bemasher/rtlamr) and [rtlamr-collect](https://github.com/bemasher/rtlamr-collect) to collect information about my utility meters. I cannot get the `ENTRYPOINT` in docker to be `rtlamr | rtlamr-collect`.

Here's my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go install github.com/bemasher/rtlamr-collect@latest
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go install github.com/bemasher/rtlamr@latest

# Use a multi-stage build to reduce our image size
FROM alpine:latest AS runtime
COPY --from=build /go/bin/rtlamr /usr/bin/rtlamr
COPY --from=build /go/bin/rtlamr-collect /usr/bin/rtlamr-collect

# Really wish this would just work as expected:
ENTRYPOINT ["rtlamr | rtlamr-collect"]
```

As a work around I have found that I can create a simple shell script and have that serve as the entry point, but that wasn't ideal because of the need for an extra file. I would not be opposed to a solution that somehow created the extra file on the fly however:

Working `dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go install github.com/bemasher/rtlamr-collect@latest
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go install github.com/bemasher/rtlamr@latest

# Use a multi-stage build to reduce our image size
FROM alpine:latest AS runtime
COPY --from=build /go/bin/rtlamr /usr/bin/rtlamr
COPY --from=build /go/bin/rtlamr-collect /usr/bin/rtlamr-collect

# I cannot for the life of me get `rtlamr | rtlamr-collect` to work as entry
# point to work around this limitation I created this small shell script that
# basically does it, and set that as the entry point which works.
ADD run.sh /usr/bin/run.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/bin/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/run.sh"]
```

Content of `run.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
rtlamr | rtlamr-collect
```

I believe a simple test case to play with might be something like this:

`dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENTRYPOINT ["echo 'hello world' | grep ell"]
```

Attempting to run this shows:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "echo 'hello world' | grep ell": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

However if you login to the Docker Container Shell and perform the same command it works as expected:

```
/ # echo 'hello world' | grep ell
hello world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to enchbladexp in the Docker Discord Server for helping come up with the solution:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go install github.com/bemasher/rtlamr-collect@latest
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go install github.com/bemasher/rtlamr@latest

# Use a multi-stage build to reduce our image size
FROM alpine:latest AS runtime
COPY --from=build /go/bin/rtlamr /usr/bin/rtlamr
COPY --from=build /go/bin/rtlamr-collect /usr/bin/rtlamr-collect

# Fully qualify the paths to the binaries
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/rtlamr | /usr/bin/rtlamr-collect"]
```

The root cause appears to have been that for whatever reason I had to fully qualify the paths of the binaries, along with provide `/bin/sh` as the entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the command you can embed it into the `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN \
    echo "#!/bin/ash" > /entrypoint.sh &&\
    echo "echo 'hello world' | grep ell" >> /entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\test> docker build -t test ./
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\test> docker run -it test:latest
hello world
```

If you need something more elaborate let me know and I'll have another dig through my previous work.

Comment: Thanks for the Response Harry! As you can see in the rest of the question that is the solution I started using, is there a way to avoid having the additional shell script, or is that my only option?

Comment: Hi @aolszowka - my mistake, here is another approach.

Comment: Awesome that worked as well, however I was able to find a way to solve the root cause and have posted it below, thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yeah, that's a great solution, but depends on how elaborate you need your entrypoint script. Glad you got what you needed!